# A strange probability inequality

Tags: pr.probability

I need help to understand the following :

*For any non-negative random variable $\zeta$: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\zeta\geq k)\leq\mathbb{E}(\zeta)\leq 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\zeta\geq k)$.*

*Therefore, if $x_0,\dotsc,x_n$ are iid random variables and $\mathbb{E}(\ln{(1+|x_0|))}<\infty$, it follows that : $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|x_k|\geq e^{\gamma k})<\infty$ for any positive constant $\gamma$.*

I don't understand where the $\gamma>0$ is coming from? Isn't it for $\gamma\geq 1$?

Comment: Looks more appropriate for Mathematics Stack Exchange https://math.stackexchange.com than MathOverflow as this is not research level.

Answer (score 4):

Every $\gamma>0$ seems ok. We have $$
\mathbb{P}(|x_k|\geqslant e^{\gamma k})\leqslant 
\mathbb{P}(1+|x_k|\geqslant e^{\gamma k})=
\mathbb{P}(\gamma^{-1}\log(1+|x_k|)\geqslant k),
$$
and the sum of these probabilities is finite.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\gamma^{-1}\ln{(1+|x|)}\geq k)\leq \mathbb{E}(\gamma^{-1}\ln{(1+|x|)})=\gamma^{-1}\mathbb{E}(\ln{(1+|x|)})$ but $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ tends to infinity when gamma tends to 0 so that product isn't < infinity ?

Comment: $\gamma$ is constant, so the sum is finite for every $\gamma>0$. It is not said that the sum is uniformly bounded for $\gamma>0$.